# Send image from google drive or get image name by google drive url

Tags: php, curl, callback, drive

I have google drive url ex: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-FuKcHPigtDdaW4a1It4ZRUtgl0RqQW/view
All I want to do is download it with PHP CURL, which is not possible. It just gives me image file with html content, where google says that they cannot let do this process. So is there any way to download this image? Or maybe is there a way to get file name, by this url? Thanks.

Inside image, when I opened it with notepad i see:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://doc-0g-bg-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/q49qhj97jrb5sim417hnaufqbno3fusq/1584296100000/13001434112142294195/*/1u-FuKcHPigtDdaW4a1It4ZRUtgl0RqQW?e=download">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

CURL:

```
<?php

function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}


grab_image('https://drive.google.com/a/file/uc?id=1u-FuKcHPigtDdaW4a1It4ZRUtgl0RqQW&export=download', 'test.jpg');

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
```